# Are custom warning messages available in Git?

Tags: git

Is there a way to add a custom warning message based on a specific task. In my case I'd like to display the following message before pushing up my local feature branch:

```
You created a migration before rebasing, did you update your migration timestamps?
```

I keep making the same mistake, and I'd prefer to have a reminder set. It would be nice if I could make this error message project specific.

Comment: Btw I ended up doing this for now.. Not super awesome but it works well enough to warn me.. ```exec < /dev/tty

OUTPUT2="$(git diff HEAD | grep schema.rb)"
if [[ -n $OUTPUT2 ]]; then
  while true; do
    read -p "[pre-push hook] Schema updated. Did you update migration filenames? (Y/n) " yn
    case $yn in
        [Yy] ) exit;;
        [Nn] ) exit 1;;
        *    ) echo "Please answer y or n.";;
    esac
  done
fi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the client side git hooks, https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks. You get a chance to intercept certain activities to look for things that might concern you. The one thing about the hooks is that they aren't part of the repo, so you have to make sure you copy them into their directory each time you clone a repo into a clean directory.